# extract-document-data comes as xml string element in json output

Tags: json, xml, marklogic

I am trying to enrich my search results with some elements taken from the "**matching**" documents, using the query option "**extract-document-data**" like

```
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
<extract-document-data selected="include">
      <extract-path>/language-version/language-version-canonical-model/title</extract-path>
      <extract-path>/language-version/language-version-canonical-model/language</extract-path>
</extract-document-data>
(...)
</options>
```

When I run the search and I ask for Json output (using the header Accept: `application/json`) I get as mix of **json** and "**strinxml**" as a result:

```
{  
  "snippet-format": "snippet",  
  "total": 564,  
  "start": 1,  
  "page-length": 10,  
  "selected": "include",  
  "results": [  
    {  
      "index": 1,  
      "uri": "ENV/CHEM/NANO(2015)22/ANN5/2",  
      "path": "fn:doc(\"ENV/CHEM/NANO(2015)22/ANN5/2\")",  
      (...)  
      "matches": [  
        {  
          "path": "fn:doc(\"ENV/CHEM/NANO(2015)22/ANN5/2\")/ns2:language-version/ns2:language-version-raw-data/*:document/*:page[22]",  
          (...)  
        }  
      ],  
      "extracted": {  
        "kind": "element",  
        "content": [  
          "&lt;language&gt;En&lt;/language&gt;",  
          "&lt;title&gt;ZINC OXIDE DOSSIERANNEX 5&lt;/title&gt;",  
          "&lt;reference&gt;ENV/CHEM/NANO(2015)22/ANN5&lt;/reference&gt;",  
          "&lt;classification&gt;2&lt;/classification&gt;",  
          "&lt;modificationDate&gt;2015-04-16T00:00:00.000+02:00&lt;/modificationDate&gt;",  
          "&lt;subject label_en=\"media\" &gt;media&lt;/subject&gt;",  
          "&lt;subject label_en=\"fish\" "&gt;fish&lt;/subject&gt;",  
        ]  
      }  
    },
```

The problem here is with the "**extracted**" part, as you can see, it looks like the **xml** elements have been simply copied as string, when I would really expect them to be converted to **json**.

Does anybody have an idea about this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MarkLogic won’t convert content. So, XML will remain XML when asking for JSON formatted search response. And since you can't really embed XML inside JSON, it gets serialized as a string.

You could try applying a REST transform on your search results, and use something like json:transform-to-json (probably with the custom config) to convert those on the fly. For instance something like this Server-side JavaScript transform:

```
/* jshint node:true,esnext:true */
/* global xdmp */

var json = require('/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy');
var config = json.config('custom');

function toJson(context, params, content) {
  'use strict';

  var response = content.toObject();

  if (response.results) {
    response.results.map(function(result) {
      if (result.extracted && result.extracted.content) {
        result.extracted.content.map(function(content, index) {
          if (content.match(/^</) && !content.match(/^<!/)) {
            result.extracted.content[index] = json.transformToJson(xdmp.unquote(content), config);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  return response;
}

exports.transform = toJson;
```

You could also convert client-side of course.

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Java Client API you can use the correct handle for each result to read the extracted items (see [ExtractedResult](http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/ExtractedResult.html) and [ExtractedItem](http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/ExtractedItem.html)):

```
SearchHandle results = queryManager.search(query, new SearchHandle());
for (MatchDocumentSummary summary : results.getMatchResults()) {
    ExtractedResult extracted = summary.getExtracted();
    // here we check to see if this result is XML format, and if so
    // we use org.w3c.dom.Document
    if ( Format.XML == summary.getFormat() ) {
        for (ExtractedItem item : extracted) {
            Document extractItem = item.getAs(new DOMHandle()).get();
            ...
        }
    // or if the result is JSON we could choose a different handle
    } else if ( Format.JSON == summary.getFormat() ) {
        for (ExtractedItem item : extracted) {
            JsonNode extractItem = item.getAs(JsonNode.class);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, this would work. In my case though, the client is a javascript application and I need to do the transform for them...